# Return null if "no row with the given identifier exists"

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got many-to-one relation between two tables. I catch

> no row with the given identifier exists

As I understood, that thing occurs, if table A can't bind table B with given id. So, how can I avoid that? It will be nice to return null object. I was trying to annotate binded field with `nullable=true`, but that doesn't fix the problem.

Also I've set `@ManyToOne(optional = true)`, but no effect.

Comment: When do you get that exception, after reading the row from the database? Do you have foreign keys active between your database tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the [solution](http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2013/02/a-weird-hibernate-exception-org-hibernate-objectnotfoundexception-no-row-with-the-given-identifier-exists/). I should annotate binded field with `@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)` statement.